# Angular 5 ng-bootstrap modal not showing correctly when called in subject subscribe method

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I wanted to display a simple modal when the subject subscribe method is called.

My appComponent class is set up very simple:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  @ViewChild('content') content;

  constructor(private as: AppService, private http: HttpClient, private modalService: NgbModal){
    as.getError().subscribe(e => {
      console.log('err '+e);
      this.open(this.content);
    });
  }

open(content){
  this.modalService.open(content);
}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/get/").subscribe(r => {
    console.log(r);
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

I am using an errorHandler to catch various errors. If an error is thrown, it is caught and send to the subject in the service. In the constructor I am subscribing the subject and would like to display a modal with the error.
The problem is it is not rendering it correctly. It appends just to the bottom of my page and doesn't show as a normal dialog.

Would like to have
[image: this]

But got
[image: this]

Comment: why don't you use the directive to create the modal instead of the service. and access the modal using the template name

Comment: I cannot follow you. I am not using directives.

Comment: Make sure that you are using Bootstrap CSS version 4.0.0 or later. What is the Bootstrap CSS version that you've got installed?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I have got bootstrap 4.1.1